# Error values-v23.xml , librerías de la interfaz

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación y me suelta este error , el problema es que he probado cambiar la versión , o la versión de las librerias que estoy usando y me sigue saliendo este error.

> values-v23/values-v23.xml
>
> Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

```
 compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nana.nana.batman"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.0.15"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionCode 22
            versionName '1.0.15'
        }
        pro {
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0.0'
        }
    }
```

Veo en internet y en el stackoverflow inglés que puede es un problema de la versión de la API de Android , pero no lo doy solucionado.

Gracias y saludos.

**SOLUCIONADO**

```
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nana.nanan.batman"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.0.15"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionCode 22
            versionName '1.0.15'
        }
        pro {
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0.0'
        }
    }
```

Es por el tema de la versión , también hay que actualizar las librerías que se pongan en el apartado de dependencias a la versión "*23.0.0"*.

Comment: Recuerda que tu versión del SDK debe SIEMPRE coincidir con la con la versión principal de la biblioteca de soporte.

Comment: Gracias , es algo que me marcaré a fuego. Lo recordaré , he perdido por esto 2 horas de chollo.

Comment: La verdad no es obligatorio actualizar las librerías.. el único problema sería, que las versiones de las librerías contrastando con tu SDK tengan ciertos cambios y éstos generen los errores; y van a existir momentos dónde tus compile no coicidan con tu SDK y es por que sencillamente todavía no existe una versión actualizada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es algo que esta "obligando" `Google` desde que inicio oficialmente con `Android Studio`.

Si defines una version de **compileSdkVersion** o **buildToolsVersion**, en tus dependencias debes usar las versiones adecuadas para esta versión.

por ejemplo:

tengo definido :

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

por lo tanto mis dependencias de las librerías de soporte deben usar esta versión!

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Si usas versiones diferentes tendrías problemas como:

> Execution failed app:processDebugResources

Al final nos están "obligando" tácitamente a estar actualizados.

Comment: Entendido , gracias .

Comment: Yo pienso que la palabra no debería ser obligado.. pero si "necesario" para el buen funcionamiento; en el SDK que hayas decidido trabajar, de otra forma si fuera obligado en pocas palabras la app no sería funcional. Por ejemplo.. tienes buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" y en tus compile son definidos en 24.2.1

Comment: @CodeNoob anteriormente usando Eclipse u otras IDE esto no era un requisito indispensable, ya que podrías tener diferente compileSdkVersion, diferente buildToolsVersion, diferente versión de librería de soporte y funciona ahora se requiere mantener las mismas versiones y estar actualizado.